# add local users to GPP managed groups

Tags: group-policy, local-system, administrative-privileges

I (hopefully:) understand the usage of GPP management of restricted groups. I do it with Item-Level targetting but have one problem which I have no clue why it is not working.

When using Local Group Member dialog box I can link any domain user I want. Also, pressing F3 shows a list of possible variables, using which I want to point to local user on the server to be included in local Administrators group.
Tried `%computername%\%username%` and `%computername%\%SID of user%` - also starting with `%domainname%` - but with no effect.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

[Local Group Member dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbHGE.png)

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your request: Which user do you want to add in the admin group? Is it always the same username on all you servers?

Comment: Let's say i have a domain and a server on which there is local user. I want that user to be added to local admins group anytime GPO updates. Only on that particular server.

Comment: It should work by writing the username in the "Name" field of the dialog box you shown in the screenshot.

Comment: First thought: "It can't be that simple!" But it is, my bad. Many thanks! :)